# Max number of textures in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I know that there is a limit of 8 textures in WebGL.

My question is that, is 8 the limit globally, or per shader/program wise?

If it's per shader/program wise limit, does that mean, once I load the textures to uniforms of one shader, I can start reusing these slots for other shaders? Say I used `TEXTURE0` for one shape, can I use `TEXTURE0` in another shape?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The limit is per draw call.  When you make a draw call, and invoke a particular shader program, you are constrained by the limit, but your next draw call can use completely different textures in the same animation frame.

Also, 8 is just the minimum guarantee.  Systems are required to support *at least eight* to be considered WebGL conformant.  But nicer graphics cards support more than eight.  You can query the max number of image textures for the platform you're on like this:

```
var maxTextures = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS);
```

You can also look for vertex textures:

```
gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)
```

Or a combination of the two:

```
gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)
```

You can also use a site like [WebGL Report](http://webglreport.com/) (Disclaimer, I'm a contributor) to look up this stat for the platform you're on (under Fragment Shader -> Max Texture Units).

*EDIT: When this answer was first written, there was another useful site called "WebGL Stats" that would show aggregate data for WebGL support in a variety of browsers.  Sadly, that site disappeared a couple years ago without warning.  But even back then, most devices supported at least 16 textures.*

Comment: Does that I mean I need to switch textures between each draw call, instead of uploading textures ahead. Which brings another question, Do I need to upload uniforms for every draw call(something else other than textures)? Are the uniforms uploaded to the program persist?

Comment: If a draw call uses different textures than the previous draw call, then yes you must re-bind the textures between draw calls.  The question about non-texture uniforms sounds like a separate question, maybe post a new question focused on that.

Comment: As of 2023, there is this useful site with statistics of adoption of webgl and webgpu: https://web3dsurvey.com/ 
It includes stats for limits and extension support. e.g.: https://web3dsurvey.com/webgl2/parameters/MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS says 100% for 16 which is the guaranteed minimum `MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` also seen on WebGL Report (so 100% of the 96% WebGL adoption).
Additionally, it says that in practice 32 is safe to assume as a minimum with 99.97% support, but 48 textures only have 28.92%, so it would have to be queried for dynamically.