# Query how much VRAM is available from web application

Tags: javascript, gpu, webgl, webassembly

Within a web context, is it possible to query a device to determine how much GPU RAM is available on the device?

Is this possible in WASM or some other exotic setup?

Any pointers others have on this question would be very helpful.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670575/978057)

Comment: Thanks! What about in WASM--is it possible to query the device VRAM in that context?

Comment: afaik wasm does not have any privileges over javascript.

Comment: "WebGL doesn't offer APIs to query the maximum amount of video memory on the system because such queries are not portable." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices